# Excel - Match in two columns with variable names

Tags: excel

I've got two lists of people and I have to check if they're in both lists. The thing is that characters are not accepted in one of the lists ("-" for instance), and the person might have omitted a last name in case they have two.

For example:

`A1           B2
John Paul   John Paul Jones
Mary Williams   Ryan Roberts
Ryan Roberts-Johnson    Mary Williams`

My formula is: `=IFERROR(MATCH($A1,$B$1:$B$1215,0),IFERROR(MATCH(LEFT($A1,FIND(" ",$A1,1)),$B$1:$B$1215,0),"No Match"))`

The idea is: if the name is the same, bring me the line where the person is. If not, look for the first name and see if you find someone with this first and bring it to me. If neither works, reply with "No Match".

But apparently the Match function only retrieves exact matches, so the First Name one doesn't work.

Is there any other way to solve this?

EDIT1: First finding: I can use the `SUBSTITUTE` formula to replace `-` with space and do the search once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the things I did to save up some time (I probably spent more time figuring out/researching than I would have if I had done ~3500 entries manually, but the learning opportunity was great.)

What I wanted: 
To search for for a cell with name + surname when I only had the surname.

What I did: I remembered about the wildcards and used them with VLOOKUP:

First I got the last name and added the star: `="*"&RIGHT($A1,LEN($A1)-FIND(" ",$A1,1))`

`=VLOOKUP(A1,$B$1:$B$1000,1,FALSE)`

And it would try and find the first one. Before that I added a check to make sure that there weren't two people with the surname (so it wouldn't throw another person there) with a simple `IF(COUNTIF($C$2:$C$2000,$D219)<=2`, and then the rest of the formula.

Something else that I noticed and serves as a reminder: `TRIM` is very important, as some of the cells had two spaces in between first name/last and some one space after the last letter of the last name. Using TRIM to create a new column made me avoid a lot of mistakes I only took a while to notice.

I believe the case is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a temporary column extracting the first name from B column.

See [this](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiZtzQr7XGkRatbXHC3X_TzRAcE) example.

Comment: That's an interesting idea!!

Comment: Did this help you..?

Comment: Not exactly. I did some testing and it didn't really work out. But then I saw a solution: using &"*". The asterisk wildcard will make it search for anything using that surname. So if I get the last name (Williams, for example) and add an asterisk before it, it will search for the first name that contains Williams.